# Angular+Django form validation at the backend

Tags: django, angular, validation

I have Angular(6) component - a form with bunch of inputs

I want to validate all inputs on server side - Django

(submit, validate using django-forms, and in case of errors - show these errors using angular)

what's the best approach to do that ?

Comment: you can read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: are you using Django-rest-framework right? Use serializers for validating

Comment: yes, but I guess there should be already some library available for frontend ?

Comment: @Tegito123 I'm using Angular2+